# Java String Translation

Tags: java, string, translation

Is it possible to translate a `String` to other language in Java? For example, if I have this code:

```
class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "Text";
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Can I translate `s` to other language in code (for example `SomeClass.translateToSomeLanguage(s)`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only place this is supported in the JDK is with `SimpleDateFormat` for formatting dates by providing a `Locale`.

You'll need an external library for everything else.

Comment: @user3666392 Use _what_?

Comment: What would be provide a `Locale`?

Comment: @user3666392 Look at the Javadoc of `SimpleDateFormat`. You can set the `Locale` in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

## Google Translate

Google provides a `Google APIs Client Library for Java` to access its [Google Translate API](https://developers.google.com/translate/) over the internet as one of their [Cloud Platform Services](https://developers.google.com/cloud/).

You can read [this RayWenderlich.com tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1448/google-translate-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-translate-text-with-google-translate-and-json-on-the-iphone), though it is probably outdated. Google revoked its version 1 of the Translate API, replacing it with a different (and commercial) version 2.

Comment: This API has to access the internet?

Comment: @CrazyProgrammer Yes, the Translate API is a commercial service provided by Google via the Internet.